# RavenDb: Why filtering while string == null filters too much?

Tags: c#, .net, filtering, ravendb

I want to filter the `EquipmentEntity` list by `Type` if it is specified (different from null). The type is a nullable string.

Request:

```cs
public class GetEquipmentsQuery : IQuery<List<EquipmentDto>> {
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }

}
```

Filtering:

```cs
var equipments = await session
.Query<EquipmentEntity>()
.Where(a => (request.Type == null || a.Type == request.Type))
.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

If the `Type` property equals null, `equipments` is an empty list. If the `Type` property has a value and there is an `EquipmentEntity` whose `Type` property has that value, it is included in the list of returned elements.

I have a problem with that condition:

```cs
var equipments = await session
.Query<EquipmentEntity>()
.Where(a => request.Type == null)
.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I tested how the filtering works with a simplified condition. Although `request.Type == null` is true, them for some reason `equipments` is empty.

I do not have this problem with very similar filtering:

```cs
var equipments = await session
.Query<EquipmentEntity>()
.Where(a => (request.Price == null || a.Price <= request.Price))
.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

In this case, if `Price` property equals null it does not affect the filtering and receives a proper list. The only difference I notice here is that `Price` property is a nullable double and `Type` property is a nullable string.

How can I make `Where` so that it filters correctly when the given `Type` property from the `request` is null?

Comment: What happens when you try `request.Type == ""` in your second query?

Comment: Will the following help ?
**Filter by non-existing field** : https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-filter-by-non-existing-field
**Filter by field presence**: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-filter-by-field

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride The same, if  `request.Type == ""`, equipments is an empty list.

Comment: @Danielle My field has already existed in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, this is working for me:

```cs
        using var session = _context.Store.OpenAsyncSession();
        
        var query = session.Query<EquipmentEntity>();
        if (request.Name != null) {
            query = query.Search(a => a.Name, $"*{request.Name}*");
        }

        if (request.Price != null) {
            query = query.Where(a => a.Price <= request.Price);
        }
        
        if (request.Type != null) {
            query = query.Where(a => a.Type == request.Type);
        }

        var equipments= await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        
        return _mapper.Map<List<EquipmentDto>>(equipments);
```

I only add further filters when I know that a `request` field is different from null. This avoids the problem of filter `Where(a => (request.Type == null || a.Type == request.Type))` because aligning to a specific value filters the list as expected.

However, this is a workaround and I would like to understand why previous approach return empty list.